# How do I join multiple hive queries?

Tags: join, hive

I am trying to join a simple query with a very ugly query that resolves to a single line.  They have a date and a userid in common but nothing else.  Alone both queries work but for the life of me I cannot get them to work together.  Can someone assist me in how I would do this?

Comment: It might help if you show us those queries.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it...when you union queries in hive it looks like you need to have an equal number of fields coming back from each.